# OneDrive upload files with REST API via resumable session

Tags: c#, rest, http, uwp, onedrive

Hi there currently I am trying to make files uploading to one drive trough REST API. But every time I am getting Exception with 401 code for non authorized

`The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.`

My code snippet

```
public async Task<string> UploadFileAsync(Account account, StorageFile file)
{
    var publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(MicrosoftConstants.ClientId)
               .WithRedirectUri(MicrosoftConstants.RedirectUri)
               .Build();

    var scopes = new string[]
    {
        "files.readwrite.all"
    };

    AuthenticationResult authToken = null;

    try
    {
        authToken = await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {              
    }

    if (authToken != null)
    {
        var postData = new
        {
            item = new
            {
                name = file.Name
            }
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData);

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create($"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/root:/{file.Name}:/createUploadSession");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.ContentLength= json.Length;
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "bearer" + authToken.AccessToken;

        using (var requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Do anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get a valid token? Have you tried with "Bearer " (capital "B") ?

Comment: Token can be a non valid if scope is wrong. Yes I have tried with capital B

Comment: You know what 401 Unauthorized is right? Your token either is not acceptable to the API or you are not applying it correctly to the request. Unrelated but you might consider using HttpClient instead of HttpWebRequest.

Comment: Yes I know. I mean scope for retrieving token is not fit for api. I have tried http client too I can update code snippet with that

Comment: Did you try `request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + authToken.AccessToken;` space after Bearer

Comment: Thank you so much. I have forgot about space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work I had to change header with authorization to

`request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + authToken.AccessToken;`